# How to fill memory as fast as possible in c#

Tags: c#, memory-management

An interviewer just asked me a peculiar question I hadn't thought about before.

*"How would you fill the memory of a computer as fast as possible in C#?"*

I answered that I would probably use some kind of recursive function, however he pointed out I would probably get a stack overflow before filling the memory.

My question is simply, how would I fill the memory of a computer as fast as possible using C#?

Comment: "try to access an Oracle database".

Comment: Maybe the question hints to unmanaged ressources on the heap like images or gdi objects.

Comment: I'd go with "I wouldn't" :D

Comment: The interviewer is **wrong**. The current JIT compiler and the x64 compiler before it use tail recursion optimizations, so a recursive function may or may not result in a stack overflow

Comment: @Luaan Hahaha I joked with that as my first answer. Such a strange question really took me off guard!

Comment: The memory is *always* filled. Sometimes with unpredictable random data, but as long as the interviewer doesn’t get more precise, that’s sufficient, thus the answer would be “by assuming it to be filled (with arbitrary data)”; you can’t get faster than that. Otherwise we need to know what kind of memory we are talking about, how it got allocated (*if* it’s supposed to be allocated), if it’s GPU accessible etc. and with what the memory is supposed to be filled. Usually, the memory is already zero-filled when you allocate it…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd go with a fork-bomb:

```
while (true) Process.Start(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

The concept is familiar, the program endlessly starts new instances of itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just allocate multiple huge buffers?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Yeah, much faster. However, empty buffers aren't necessarily taken from RAM - there's pre-zeroed memory pages for that purpose - they are only allocated when you actually write some data. And this is done on the OS level, so it's kind of hard to bypass. Making copies of some image would probably be a better choice. The main "advantage" of a fork bomb isn't the memory use, though - it's how it tends to kill the whole computer by flooding it with high priority work.

Comment: How about fill but don't cause page fault and moving pages to disks.

Comment: This will eventually make CPU more occupied and make system unresponsive. This does not answer question completely.

Comment: @AkashKava That is a good point. Perhaps my question should have been "How would you fill the memory of a computer as fast as possible in C#, without crashing the system?"  Would this warrant a new post or an edit of this post?

Comment: @Josh is n't it implied? Any program we would write, it should work without crashing? Otherwise wouldn't question be "write program to crash" ?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but I'd go with something like:

```
while(true) { Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024); }
```

Comment: This definitely throws an Out of Memory exception. Thanks for your answer I think this is more what I was looking for, should have been much clearer in my question!

Comment: I didn't mean that in a negative way that's what I was looking for! Fill the memory but not crash the system!

Comment: Yeah, till you edited it read as if it was a bad thing. I deleted my comment :-)

Comment: Apologies! I went to hit for a new line and occidentally posted, thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

1. Fork-Bomb, this will eventually make CPU very busy, but not necessarily fill the memory. If you have GBs of memory and a small program, Windows MMU might eventually swap not used (previous forks) to disk and still keep memory free for other program. The only problem is, this does not fill memory instead it simply makes system unresponsive.
2. Virtual Memory, by allocating huge objects using Marshal.AllocHGlobal or similar functions, you may think you are filling memory, but once again, but OS is smarter, if you are just allocating memory and not using them to read again, OS will once again page them back to disk, still not occupying all memory. This is still virtual memory and OS will allow you to MAX memory given by .net guidelines, then it will start throwing no more memory without actually consuming all of memory.
3. Physical Memory, Now this is tricky, first of all, you cannot access physical memory in Windows under normal circumstances in any application. If you really want to fill in the memory (Physical memory) then you have to write a kernel mode driver to do it.
4. **[AllocateUserPhysicalPages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366528(VS.85).aspx)** function. This is the only Windows API which lets you allocate physical memory, (which in a way fills in memory faster) making it unavailable for other processes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366528(VS.85).aspx SQL Server uses this and I believe even other databases would be using it to pre allocate physical memory, this memory is faster and mainly used for caching purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bunch of objects and avoid them being garbage collected.

call kill() and enjoy.

```
void kill()
{
    while(true)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(fill));
}

void fill(Object o)
{
    List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
    while(true)
        list.Add(new Object());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Test\\BigFile.any");
```

**UPDATE**

I thought the code itself tells everything. So, locate an any big file in your computer for example a movie file located like "D:\Movies\BigMovieFile.mp4". And read that file as string, because `string` is very memory exhausting type. In 32 bit applications 1Gb file will be enough to blowup the memory. Since 64 bit applications will use all the memory of your computer, either a larger file must be selected or the reading process must be repeated. **I think this method will be fast as possible.**

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: File not found.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that has a payload and implements a finalizer. Then spawn a number of highest priority threads that all create instances of this class. They don't have to hold on to them as they'll go on the finalizer queue. The finalizer thread will not be able to keep up with the rate of incoming objects to be finalized and you'll effectively fill up process memory. On a 32-bit system that may not be enough to fill computer memory, but on 64-bit you should be able to on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear this question was answered in more than six years. In case anyone is still curious, the following code works.

```
using System.Management;

ObjectQuery objQuery = new("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtObjSearcher = new(objQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection mgmtObjColl = mgmtObjSearcher.Get();

var mgmtObj = mgmtObjColl.OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

long freeBytes = long.Parse(mgmtObj.GetPropertyValue("FreePhysicalMemory").ToString()) * 1024;

long numOfArrays = freeBytes / 2000000000;

byte[][] memArray = new byte[numOfArrays][];
for (int i = 0; i < memArray.Length; i++)
{
    memArray[i] = new byte[2000000000];
}

for(int i = 0; i < memArray.Length; i++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < memArray[i].Length; x++)
    {
        memArray[i][x] = (byte)x;
    }
}
```